# Edit email template that is sent on creation of a manual order

Tags: orders, email

If I create a manual order in the admin section the customer is notified by email. I need to edit certain text that goes into this email but I don't know from where I can do this?

The specific text seems to be in one of the language files

```
   app/locale/en_US/Mage_Payment.csv
```

But when I tried editing it from here there was no change in the email so maybe I'm looking in the wrong place.

All help appreciated. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by **Transactional Emails**. Go to **System -> Transactional Emails**. Select Template to "New Order". Now you can change as required, But don't forget to assign this template to new order. Go to **System -> Configuration -> Sales Email -> Order** .

NB: If you can change then it will be effect from frontend order email.